Install applications via Intune for Azure VMs
I'm exploring options to streamline the process to install application for a group of Azure VMs (specifically for AVD Azure Virtual desktop VMs). Traditionally we will create a vm image with the required apps and deploy the vms based of that image.
I'm looking into options such as Intune or utilizing the MSIX packages (via Azure host pool), can anyone share their experience working with the mentioned approaches or share their practices?
Creating images is quite a tedious task when we have to multiple apps (Office365, web browsers, web conference and 3rd party apps) to install or update.
